# Meteor recursive template doesn't work

Tags: templates, recursion, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I tried to have a recursive template like this:

```
<template name="generate">
  {{#if elements}}
    {{#each elements}}
      <div>{{#if elements}}{{> generate}}{{/if}}</div>
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    {{> generate elements=getElements}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

with the helper:

```
Template.generate.helpers({
  getElements: function() {
    return Elements.find()
  }
})
```

and the "Elements" data object:

```
[{ 
  _id : "fgQ4GHrrZGFFGWPZQ", 
  elements" : [{
    _id : "hY8iAYJC4KBwGKN84",  
    elements : [] 
  }]
},{ 
  _id : "rtMNfaQYwqzNTYqoD", 
  elements : [{
    _id : "p2wJeGdtiGMYBQtpW",  
    elements : [] 
  }]
}]
```

I'm running into an issue where the keyboard events become unresponsive and other functionality ceases to work. Were templates not designed to handle this kind of recursion? If so, I'll try a different approach but I figured this would work though. Anyone else seeing this or have any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit: This will work. My problem was setting up a keyboard event handler on the "rendered" callback which was being called more than once (each time the template was rendered) which caused the issue I mentioned. I would delete this question but stackoverflow. Thanks everybuddy!

Comment: I'm quite sure templates can handle recursion, so you probably have infinite recursion. Remember that empty arrays (`[]`) are truthy.

Comment: Note to self: always copy/paste instead of using own words, so no stupid typos arise ([empty arrays are falsy in #if-block in Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#ifunless), as (kind of) mentioned in one of the answers below).

Comment: Looks like this can work after all. I had bugs elsewhere in my code. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors here.

**First.** you have a helper named  `getElements` and you are calling it like `elements`

**Second** you are calling the template into the same template `{{> generate}}`

```
<template name="generate">
  {{#if elements}}
    {{#each  getElements}}
      <div>{{#if elements}}{{> anotherTemplateName}}{{/if}}</div>
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    {{> generate elements=getElements}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Also how the `elements` helper looks? `{{#if elements}}`

A suggestion will be using nested templates here.

```
<template name="generate">
      {{#if elements}}
        {{> generateExample}}
      {{else}}
        {{> generate elements=getElements}}
      {{/if}}
    </template>

<!-- Generate Example Template -->

    <template name="generateExample">
            {{#each  getElements}}
              <div>{{#if elements}}{{> anotherTemplateName}}{{/if}}</div>
            {{/each}}
    </template>
```

Take a look into this [Understanding Spacebars](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/) for a better learning experience

Comment: There were no errors. I had other stuff elsewhere in my code that was causing issues. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Javascript, [Spacebars considers an empty array `[]` to be falsy](http://meteorpad.com/pad/qdne2FmNxcdMqk4B2/spacebars%20empty%20array%20falsy). So the initial `{{#if elements}}` on leaf nodes (which have `elements: []`) will be false, triggering the `{{> generate elements=getElements}}` which ultimately causes an infinite recursion.

You could fix this by removing the `{{#if}}` altogether, and then calling `{{> generate elements=getElements}}` when you initially include `generate`:

```html
<body>
    {{> generate elements=getElements}}
</body>

<template name="generate">
    {{#each elements}}
        <div>{{#if elements}}{{> generate}}{{/if}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: This wouldn't have worked because I didn't want to assign a helper to the body template. Thanks for the help anyways!