# Meteor model tree structure: best way getting id and how to create nested list-output

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have an article which consits of six sections. Every section has multiple list-items. Also some items can be selected to be merged in a group.
Therefore I decided to use a model tree structures with parent references:

**docs in collection**

```
_id: item_1, parent: null, title: 'item 1' 
_id: item_2, parent: null, title: 'item 2'
_id: item_3, parent: item_2, title: 'item 3'
_id: item_4, parent: item_2, title: 'item 4'
_id: item_5, parent: null, title: 'item 5'
```

I think this is the easiest way to put some elements to another group. I'm also thinking of the best way building an _id. So I thought to use the _id of the article itself, the section-number and a counting number: aid_2_4 (=second section and fourth element).

1. Would this be a good way or do you have a smarter idea? Maybe I just need the counting number?
2. For the counting number I would do the following thing: Before every insert I will count the elements in this collection with filter, so I just put the new value as the _id. Is there any disadvantage for doing it this way?
3. And my last question is how to get this output in a quick way?

**output**

```
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2
    <ul>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>item 5</li>
```

As editors could change/create groups, this output should be updated automatically (like everything else in meteor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some blaze template recursion!

html:

```
<template name="section">
  <ul>
    {{#each children}}
      <li>{{title}}</li>
      {{#if hasChildren}}
        {{>section}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.section.helpers({
  children: function(){
    return Sections.find({ parent: this._id });
  },
  hasChildren: function(id){
    return Sections.find({ parent: this._id }).count() > 0;
  }
});
```

Or something close to that. [Here's a related q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689843/meteor-recursive-template-doesnt-work) that might also be of help.

Thanks to @Mathias Eckhart for turning this into a [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/ccTRc7dszJr4B34Xw/Meteor-Tree) and fixing the data context issues.